# Spring RestTemplate call to HTTPS *without* HttpClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate

Trying to make REST calls with RestTemplate using the server cert as the client cert to make calls with.

Don't ask me why :-), but I don't want to use Apache's HttpClient. I just think it's overkill.

I've seen code that uses regular JDK's `SSLContext` to set things up system-wide, i.e., set up `SSLContext` and the call `SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext)` as in this code:

```
// ... keymanagers, trustmanagers are omitted here
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keymanagers, trustmanagers, new SecureRandom());
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

However, I saw a GitHub comment here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6493) that states that setting `SSLContext` as default like that isn't really a good idea.

So, my question is: outside of having to use HttpClient, is there a way to use the `sslContext` configured in the code snippet above in `RestTemplate` setup somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default `requestFactory` in the `restTemplate` by doing

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new MyCustomRequestFactory());
```

Have a look at `org.springframework.http.client.SkipSslVerificationHttpRequestFactory` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/cloudfoundry/servlet/SkipSslVerificationHttpRequestFactory.java) for an example of setting SSLContext in your request factory.